# Prove that span(u,v) is a subspace of span(w1, w2, w3).

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that they are asking to prove that all linear combinations of $u$ and $v$ is a subspace for all the linear combinations of $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$. However, I am unsure on where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Let $w_1, w_2, w_3, u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $u, v \in \operatorname{Span} \{ w_1, w_2, w_3 \}$. Show that $\operatorname{Span} \{ u, v\} \subseteq \operatorname{Span} \{ w_1, w_2, w_3 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf u \in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf w_1,\mathbf w_2,\mathbf w_3)$, let $\mathbf u = u_1\mathbf w_1+u_2\mathbf w_2+u_3\mathbf w_3$.

Similarly, let $\mathbf v = v_1\mathbf w_1+v_2\mathbf w_2+v_3\mathbf w_3$.

Let $\mathbf x \in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf u,\mathbf v)$, i.e. $\mathbf x=a\mathbf u+b\mathbf v$ where $a,b \in \Bbb R$.

Then, $\mathbf x=a(u_1\mathbf w_1+u_2\mathbf w_2+u_3\mathbf w_3) + b(v_1\mathbf w_1+v_2\mathbf w_2+v_3\mathbf w_3)$.

So, $\mathbf x=(au_1+bv_1)\mathbf w_1+(au_2+bv_2)\mathbf w_2+(au_3+bv_3)\mathbf w_3$.

Therefore, $\mathbf x \in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf w_1,\mathbf w_2,\mathbf w_3)$.

---

Since $\mathbf x \in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) \implies \mathbf x \in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf w_1,\mathbf w_2,\mathbf w_3)$, we conclude that $\operatorname{span}(\mathbf u,\mathbf v) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(\mathbf w_1,\mathbf w_2,\mathbf w_3)$.

Comment: This was very insightful and makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Let $x \in \operatorname{Span} \{ u, v\}$,

Hence you can write $x = c_1 u + c_2 v$

Express $u$ as linear combination of $w_i$'s.

Express $v$ as linear combination of $w_i$'s.

If you can show that $x$ in the form of linear combination of $w_i$'s, then you have shown what you want.